# how do I customize an existing force site to match our new website?

Tags: force.com

I have no idea what I am doing.  Help.

I inherited a page on force.com that is out of brand for the company.  I need to update the look and feel and one tiny bullet point.  How do I do that?

This is the page that needs editing:
https://mnchorale.secure.force.com/donate/PatronDonate__PublicDonation

Answer (score 0):

You need to edit PatronDonate__PublicDonation.page. Visualforce supports HTML tags so you can take most of the thing from existing page.

Comment: The Salesforce Support team created PatronDonate__PublicDonation.page. so how do I access it?  I have no knowledge of Visualforce.

Comment: You need visualforce expertise to do that. from setup->visual force pages -> PatronDonate__PublicDonation then edit it.